# Javascript rendering to HTML canvas extremely slowly

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to render a grid to an HTML canvas by rendering individual squares (because later on the cells should not all look the same but have individual behaviors).

I have created a minimal example which shows the performance issues I am having. Running this script nearly freezes my browser, until it offers to stop the script for me because it's detecting that this script is running too slowly.

I have a similar example running the Javascript framework p5.js and it's running fine in terms of performance.
However, I want to move to basic Javascript without that framework.

Here's the minimal example causing the performance issues. I'd be happy about any suggestions why this might run so slowly...

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;

let grid_width = 50;
let grid_height = grid_width;
let grid = [];

class Cell {
  constructor(i,j) {
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    this.width = width / grid_width;
    this.height = height / grid_height;
    this.x = i*this.width;
    this.y = j*this.height;
  }

  render(color) {
    context.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    context.lineWidth = .25;
    if(color) {
      context.fillStyle = color;
    }
    context.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
  }
}

for(let i = 0; i <= grid_width; i++) {
  if(!(grid[i])) {
    grid[i] = [];
  }
  for(let j = 0; j <= grid_height; j++) {
    grid[i][j] = new Cell(i, j);
  }
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  grid.forEach(row => {
    row.forEach(cell => {
      cell.render();
    });
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

// This call to draw will run very slowly!
// draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- <script src="p5.js"></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas><br>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please note that I have commented out the call to draw() because my script also wrecks the "Run code snippet" button on this site...

Comment: are you using p5.js?

Comment: No, this was my attempt at removing p5.js from my project.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

Brief explanation.`rect` is a canvas `path command`. So `fill` and `stroke` redraws all the paths between `beginPath()` and `endPath` with latest `fillStyle` and `strokeStyle`. In you case your loop first draw only first rect, then draw first and second so on.
And yes, your color, after you will fixed `if` statement inside method, always will be applied to all cells.

So I purpose a little bit different code here. First. I replace `rect`  with `strokeRect` and `fillRect` which applied immediatly. Second. I remove your `if` condition.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;

let grid_width = 50;
let grid_height = grid_width;
let grid = [];

class Cell {
  constructor(i,j) {
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    this.width = width / grid_width;
    this.height = height / grid_height;
    this.x = i*this.width;
    this.y = j*this.height;
  }

  render(color) {
    context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    context.lineWidth = .25;
    context.fillStyle = color || '#FFFFFF';
    context.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}

for(let i = 0; i <= grid_width; i++) {
  if(!(grid[i])) {
    grid[i] = [];
  }
  for(let j = 0; j <= grid_height; j++) {
    grid[i][j] = new Cell(i, j);
  }
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  grid.forEach(row => {
    row.forEach(cell => {
      cell.render(Math.random()>0.5?"#FF00FF":undefined);
    });
  });
  //requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

// This call to draw will run very slowly!
 draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- <script src="p5.js"></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas><br>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't help because I eventually want to have an animation. However the linked duplicate question answered all my question.

Answer (score 0):

Commented `requestAnimationFrame(row)` function call. Because there is no such function is present. Now code works smoothly for me.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;

let grid_width = 50;
let grid_height = grid_width;
let grid = [];

class Cell {
  constructor(i,j) {
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    this.width = width / grid_width;
    this.height = height / grid_height;
    this.x = i*this.width;
    this.y = j*this.height;
  }

  render(color) {
    context.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    context.lineWidth = .25;
    if(color) {
      context.fillStyle = color;
    }
    context.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
  }
}

for(let i = 0; i <= grid_width; i++) {
  if(!(grid[i])) {
    grid[i] = [];
  }
  for(let j = 0; j <= grid_height; j++) {
    grid[i][j] = new Cell(i, j);
  }
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  grid.forEach(row => {
    row.forEach(cell => {
      cell.render();
    });
  });
  //requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

// This call to draw will run very slowly!
 draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- <script src="p5.js"></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas><br>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand, requestAnimationFrame() is a Javascript standard function. Anyway, the linked duplicate question answered my question.